# LaTeX probability tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, tikz-trees

Please could you tell me if the [Probability tree](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/probability-tree/) posted on 2006-12-14 by Kjell Magne Fauske can be done with three branches instead of just two.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Do you mean this tree http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/probability-tree/? Exactly where do you want to add branches? You may want to add some example code to your question.

Comment: Yes, I do, that is the exact example.  Instead of two branches coming off the first node (Bag 1) I want three.

Answer (score 7):

- To add another "Bag 2" branch, add another `node[bag]` structure.
- To add another end branch, add another `child { node[end] {}}` to a `node[bag]` structure.

You can merely copy and paste the right parts to achieve it.

Here is a simplified example of http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/probability-tree/ where another of each sorts of branches has been added:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}

% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=4em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[bag] {Bag 1}
    child {
        node[bag] {Bag 2}% This is the first of three "Bag 2"
        child {
                node[end] {}
            }
            child {
                node[end] {}
            }
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {Bag 2}
            child {
                node[end] {}
            }
            child {
                node[end] {}
            }
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {Bag 2}
            child {% Here are three children, hence three end branches
                node[end] {}
            }
            child {
                node[end] {}
            }
            child {
                node[end] {}
            }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of code]

Comment: Can this be done till the second step (where it says bag 2) only? I'm trying so much time and it constantly collapses.

Comment: can you do it so that on the second step all three have 3 branches