# Drawing Tree Diagram using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Would like to ask if someone could help me draw this tree diagram using Latex. Any assistance will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far? This is not a terribly hard diagram to draw. It requires some typing though and it's easier to help someone perfect their code, rather than write it from scratch (as much as I love Tikz).

Comment: I was going to advise you to use the `forest` package but then I found this question. The answer is perfect for your case. It even has the nodes at the bottom: [Problem with probability tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166274/4778)

Comment: Some other related questions: [Making a probability tree using tikzpicture / forest](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193848) and [Draw 5 period binomial tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227414)

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39256/latex-probability-tree?rq=1, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237483/how-to-use-tikz-and-macros-to-very-efficiently-draw-recombining-binomial-trees-w and quite a lot more....

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreciate the links you provided me with