# Probability Tree

Tags: tikz-trees

How can I make a probability tree that looks like this[image: probability tree example]

I've checked this [LaTeX probability tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39256/latex-probability-tree)
but I can't get it to work with just one child

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider looking at the `forest` package. [Documentation here](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east, math content, anchor=base west}
[,phantom[A[a][1-a]][B[b][1-b]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Sandy G's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701273/) is TeXnically impeccable, but it reflects the question's mathematically questionable assumptions about the structure.

If this is a probability tree, then I believe the structure is not what you're assuming. There are actually two trees (or these are part of a larger tree), though it certainly may make sense to draw them as one. Each of those trees consists of a root (e.g. `A`) and two children (e.g. `a` and `1-a`). The point is that `a + (1-a) = 1`, since probabilities sum to `1`. That is, `a` is not a child of `1`: there is no only child and no further level.

So I suggest the following code would better reflect the semantics, even though it is not the structure you requested.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=0,math content,anchor=parent},
  delay={%
    for children={%
      content/.process={Ow{content}{\mathsf{#1}}}
    },
  }
  [,phantom
    [A
      [a]
      [1-a]
    ]
    [B
      [b]
      [1-b]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: probability trees with phantom root and sum of probabilities always 1]